# C++11 Pure virtual 'templated' return type in non-templated base class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, virtual

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

I'm trying to created a linked list of various types. In order to accomplish this, I figured polymorphism would be a great way to go about.

I have two classes, AttributeBase and Attribute. AttributeBase is used by AttributeSet, which just stores the start and end points of the linked list of Attribute<T>'s (as AttributeBase*'s) and does modification on the list. AttributeBase is a base class of Attribute<T> that is only in the design for the sake of making generic pointers. Attribute<T>, of course, is the specific type of AttributeBase where the actual value is stored. The main data of each Attribute<T> is an inherited string (the attribute's name, or 'key' if you will) and a value of type T.

So, thus far I have (simplified):

```
class AttributeBase
{
  public:
    AttributeBase() = delete;
    AttributeBase* GetNext() { return next; };
    AttributeBase* GetPrev() { return prev; };
    std::string GetName() { return name; };
    //Sometimes I need to get/set the value stored in a derived class
    //But, how would I define the function here since the return
    //type is of type T as defined in Attribute?
    virtual ???? GetValue = 0;
    virtual void SetValue(????) = 0;

    friend class AttributeSet;
  private:
    AttributeBase* next = nullptr;
    AttributeBase* prev = nullptr;
    std::string name;
};

template <class T>
class Attribute : public AttributeBase
{
  public:
    Attribute( std::string _name, T _value ){ name = _name; value = _value };
    T GetValue(){ return value; };
    void Setvalue(T){ value = T; };
  private:
    T value;
};

class AttributeSet
{
  public:
    template <class T>
    void Add(std::string,T); //Add an Attribute<T>(std::string,T) to the list
    void Delete(std::string);
    bool Contains(std::string _name); //Scan the list to determine if an
                                      //attribute with name of _name exists
    template <class T>
    T Get(std::string); //Scan the list for 'name' and return
                        //AttributeBase*->GetValue()
  private:
    AttributeBase* start = nullptr;
    AttributeBase* end = nullptr;
}
```

Since I tried to keep AttributeBase generic and non-templated (to avoid strongly-typed start and end pointers in AttributeSet), this brings up a problem. How do I specify an as-of-yet unspecified return type for the virtual function BaseAttribute::GetValue(). I first tried using `auto`, got a compile error.

Being as no instances of AttributeBase are ever actually created (and the default constructor deleted) I figured it would be possible to leave out GetValue and define it in the derived class. However, if I try *AttributeBase->GetValue() it errors out since GetValue() isn't defined in AttributeBase, only the subclasses. You would think the compiler would know that the pointer has to point to a derived class (the only derived type) since AttributeBase cannot be directly constructed.

So, in order to use GetValue() I have to know the type of the previous value ahead of time to be able to cast the AttributeBase* to an Attribute*. This would be trivial if AttributeBase itself were templated and contained a value T type. I could then just access AttributeBase*->type to determine the type of pointer I need to cast. However, like I said, templating AttributeBase destroys the intended use of the object.

More than likely, I'm going about this in a completely wrong way (yet again). But at this point I am stuck for ideas. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you give an example of code that would use `AttributeBase::GetValue` or `AttributeBase::SetValue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a truly general solution doesn't exist. You just can't get any arbitrary type from a base class because all your overrides of your base class virtual function have to have the same return type.

That leaves you two options.

First, you can decide in advance that you're going to have your list hold any object that derives from some common base type. This will severely limit what you can put into your list, but at least you have full freedom with those objects once they're there.

Second, depending on what you want to actually do with the objects once they're in your list, you can look at the new [Boost.TypeErasure](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure.html) library. If all you need to do with list is, say, output them all, or some either small amount of operations, this can help you get there.

Comment: I'd point out that you can have overrides with different return types if the types are covariant. Although this isn't really applicable in this specific case.

Comment: I already use Boost::Asio for my server code (so much simpler!) so I suppose another bit of Boost won't hurt too much. I'll have a look at it and report back soon hopefully. I should note that I'm new to Boost, so this may take a little while ;)

Comment: @FrançoisMoisan You're right, in this case I intend to store standard types in my list.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Barry! boost::type_erasure did the trick! I hassled with my package manager getting 1.54 installed and it was a little difficult to understand, but as long as I got what I needed done!

Answer (score 1):

Since the signatures of `GetValue` and `SetValue` depend on a type, they need to be templates.  But they can be template members without requiring a class template.

```
class AttributeBase
{
  public:
    template <typename T> T GetValue() const;
    template <typename T> void SetValue(T);
//...
};

template <typename T>
T AttributeBase::GetValue() const
{
    return dynamic_cast<Attribute<T>&>(*this).GetValue();
}

template <typename T>
void AttributeBase::SetValue(T val)
{
    dynamic_cast<Attribute<T>&>(*this).SetValue(val);
}

template <typename T>
T AttributeSet::Get(std::string const& name) const
{
    // (assuming a private helper method Find().)
    const AttributeBase* attr = Find(name);
    if ( !attr )
        throw std::invalid_argument("attribute not in set");
    return attr->GetValue<T>();
}
```

One gotcha, though: these functions will all throw an exception if you happen to use the wrong type.  And `SetValue` might automatically deduce its template argument, and might do so incorrectly.  For example, if `a` is a `AttributeBase&` reference which is really an `Attribute<long int>`, then `a.SetValue(1)` is the same as `a.SetValue<int>(1)`, which will throw.  The correct expression would be `a.SetValue<long int>(1)` (or `a.SetValue(1L)`, but I'd prefer the explicit template argument).

Comment: That's pretty brilliant, I hadn't thought about that. If they're templated, they don't necessarily need to be virtual... But, if I did it this way, then I wouldn't be able to something like AttributeSet.Set("thename", 25) without doing something like storing a value in AttributeBase that represents the type used. Then I'd have to switch on it pretty much every time I wanted to set an ambiguous (int, long, short, etc) value. I just finished it with Boost recommended below (which is why I'm going to mark it as best), but I will try your way as well and see how it goes =D

Comment: I managed to pull it off your way as well =D One thing of note though, was that because I was using pointers (this is, after all, a linked list) I had to change dynamic_cast to static_cast. I was getting the errors: error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘this’ (of type ‘class AttributeBase* const‘) to type ‘class Attribute<int>\* const’ (source type is not polymorphic) as well as cannot dynamic_cast ‘\*(AttributeBase\*)this’ (of type ‘class AttributeBase’) to type ‘class Attribute<int>&’ (source type is not polymorphic)

Comment: To fix the "source type is not polymorphic" errors, you would just need to make the destructor of `AttributeBase` virtual (which is probably a good idea anyway).

Comment: I had a destructor, however it wasn't marked virtual. It is now.